# Transferring Code from two machines

Tags: java, error-handling, polygon

So I am working on a code for a Java related project with a partner, but when he sent me his code, nothing was working right. I am broadening this question to all things related to transferring code from two different Eclipse environment. We are both running 1.6 I believe.

The program itself is supposed to open a JFrame with a black background with three buttons on top (Load, Read, clear) and make straight lines based on clicks, closing the shape when you right click. It works well on his Mac, but not on mine. We are both using Eclipse. (I also tested on Dr. Java).

We are newbies so be gentle :)

HERE IS THE PROBLEM:

After he compiles and clicks a few times: (I cant upload pictures without a rep of 10)
http://i49.tinypic.com/nwwsqf.jpg
After I compile:
http://i50.tinypic.com/2lxdkyg.png

Thanks for the help. I hope this will help others as well.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Shape;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PolygonMaker extends JFrame {

    private List<Polygon> polygonList = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
    public Polygon polygonInProgress = new Polygon();
    JPanel drwaingPanel;
    JPanel buttonsPanel;

    public PolygonMaker() {
        polygonList.add(polygonInProgress);
    }

    public static void main(String srg[]) {

        new PolygonMaker().generateDrwaingArea();

    }

    public void generateDrwaingArea() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(400, 300);
        setTitle("Polygon Maker");
        setVisible(true);
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    polygonInProgress.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                    System.out.println("clicked");
                } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    boolean fill = e.isShiftDown();
                    System.out.println("shift pressed");
                    if (polygonInProgress.size() > 2) {
                        recordPolygon(fill);
                        polygonInProgress = new Polygon();
                        polygonList.add(polygonInProgress);
                    }
                }
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        buttonsPanel = createButtonsPanel();

        drwaingPanel = new JPanel();
        drwaingPanel.setBackground(Color.black);

        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(drwaingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JButton loadData = new JButton("Load Data");
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        loadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                File poly = new File(
                        "C:\\Users\\Raghav\\Desktop\\poly.dat");
                try {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(poly);
                    Object options[] = { "Ok", "Cancel" };
                    int selection = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    new JFrame(),
                                    "Loading File overides current data .Continue loading?",
                                    "Loading File overides current data .Continue loading?",
                                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
                                    options, options[1]);

                    if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        remove(drwaingPanel);                       
                        remove(buttonsPanel);
                        drwaingPanel = new JPanel();
                        drwaingPanel.setBackground(Color.black);                        
                        buttonsPanel = createButtonsPanel();
                        add(drwaingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);                     
                        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        validate();
                        polygonList = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
                        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                            String line = scanner.nextLine();
                            Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
                            int numberOfPoints = Integer.parseInt(line
                                    .substring(0, line.indexOf(32)));
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(32) + 1);
                            String fillStatus = line.substring(0,
                                    line.indexOf(32));
                            System.out.println(fillStatus);
                            if (fillStatus.equals("false"))
                                polygon.setFillStatus(false);
                            else if (fillStatus.equals("true"))
                                polygon.setFillStatus(true);
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(32) + 1);
                            String isCompleted = line.substring(0,
                                    line.indexOf(32));
                            System.out.println(isCompleted);
                            if (isCompleted.equals("false"))
                                polygon.setFillStatus(false);
                            else if (isCompleted.equals("true"))
                                polygon.setFinished(true);
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(32) + 1);
                            String redValue = line.substring(0,
                                    line.indexOf(32));
                            System.out.println(redValue);
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(32) + 1);
                            String greenValue = line.substring(0,
                                    line.indexOf(32));
                            System.out.println(greenValue);
                            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(32) + 1);
                            String yellowValue = line.substring(0,
                                    line.length());
                            System.out.println(yellowValue);

                            polygon.color = new Color(Integer
                                    .parseInt(redValue), Integer
                                    .parseInt(greenValue), Integer
                                    .parseInt(yellowValue));

                            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
                                line = scanner.nextLine();
                                int x = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,
                                        line.indexOf(32)));
                                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(32) + 1);
                                int y = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,
                                        line.length()));
                                polygon.add(new Point(x, y));
                            }

                            polygonList.add(polygon);


                        }


                        polygonInProgress= new Polygon();
                        polygonList.add(polygonInProgress); 

                        validate();



                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),
                            "Cannot find poly.dat");
                }

                validate();


            }
        });
        JButton saveData = new JButton("Save Data");
        saveData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File poly = new File("C:\\Users\\Raghav\\Desktop\\poly.dat");

                try {
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter(poly));
                    for (Polygon polygon : polygonList) {
                        try {

                            bufferedWriter.write(polygon.size() + " "
                                    + polygon.isFilled() + " "
                                    + polygon.isFinished() + " "
                                    + polygon.color.getRed() + " "
                                    + polygon.color.getGreen() + " "
                                    + polygon.color.getBlue());
                            bufferedWriter.newLine();

                            for (int i = 0; i < polygon.size(); i++) {
                                bufferedWriter
                                        .write(polygon.getPoints().get(i).x
                                                + " "
                                                + polygon.getPoints().get(i).y);
                                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("clear called");
                remove(drwaingPanel);
                drwaingPanel = new JPanel();
                drwaingPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
                add(drwaingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                remove(buttonsPanel);
                buttonsPanel = createButtonsPanel();
                add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                validate();
                polygonList = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
                polygonInProgress = new Polygon();
                polygonList.add(polygonInProgress);

            }
        });

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        buttonsPanel.add(loadData);
        buttonsPanel.add(saveData);
        buttonsPanel.add(clear);


        return buttonsPanel;

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (Polygon polygon : polygonList)
            polygon.paintComponent(g);
    }

    private void recordPolygon(boolean fill) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        polygonInProgress.setFillStatus(fill);
        polygonInProgress.setFinished(true);
        remove(buttonsPanel);
        remove(drwaingPanel);
        drwaingPanel = new JPanel();
        drwaingPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        buttonsPanel = createButtonsPanel();
        add(drwaingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        validate();
        repaint();

        // polygonList.add(polygonInProgress);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "New " + polygonInProgress.size()
                + "-gon recorded \n " + (polygonList.size())
                + " polygons in all");

    }

}
```

and...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polygon {

    static final int POINT_SIZE = 0;
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public Color color = new Color(rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255),
            rnd.nextInt(255));
    private boolean isFilled = false;
    private boolean isFinished = false;
    private Point lastPointOfPloygon;

    public Polygon() {

    }

    public void write(PrintStream ps) {

    }

    public void read(Scanner scanner) {

    }

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return isFinished;

    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return isFilled;

    }

    public List<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean isFilled) {
        this.isFilled = isFilled;
    }

    public void setFillStatus(boolean status) {
        isFilled = status;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paint commponebt calles");
        g.setColor(color);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {

            if (i == points.size() - 1) {
                System.out.println("last point");
                if (isFinished == true) {
                    System.out.println(isFinished + "connect");
                    if (isFilled == true) 
                    g.fillOval(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, 5, 5);
                    g.drawLine(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y,
                            points.get(0).x, points.get(0).y);
                }
            } else {
                if (isFilled == true) 
                    g.fillOval(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, 5, 5);
                    g.drawLine(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y,
                            points.get(i + 1).x, points.get(i + 1).y);

            }
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return points.size();
    }

    public void add(Point point) {
        points.add(point);

    }

    public void setFinished(Boolean finishedValue) {
        isFinished = finishedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735493/using-swing-java-to-make-program

Comment: "The program itself is supposed to open a JFrame with a black background with three buttons on top (Load, Read, clear) and make straight lines based on clicks, closing the shape when you right click. It works and runs on his Mac, but not on mine. We are both using Eclipse. (I also tested on Dr. Java)."

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Code-Guru can read. where is the question there?

Comment: @JustaBreitGuy I still don't see a question in your comment. In English, a question ends with a question mark.

Comment: @code-guru Why would it run perfectly in his eclipse and only bring a grey screen on mine.

Comment: I suggest simplifying your code to figure out the problem. You could start by writing a simple program that creates a blank window. Do you see the same behavior with this simplified program? If not, add the smallest amount of logic to it that you can and still have a compileable, runnable program and try again. Rinse, Wash, Repeat.

Comment: What does your partner send you: source code (*.Java) or bytecode (*.Class)?  Do you both have the same project structure in Eclipse? I wholeheartedly agree with the advice to start with much smaller sample: 5-10 lines of code from each machine.

Comment: The bite a bullet and run a small sample: just two short classes with your code calling his method that does virtually nothing.

Comment: One more question: have you actually seen your partner's code work on his machine with your own eyes?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes I have screenshots

Comment: @knowbody How does it feel knowing your turning future coders in the wrong direction? Talk nice, teach, dont be a ass.

Comment: @JustaBreitGuy you're not your and an ass - English lesson

Comment: @knowbody Very impressive defense mechanism!

Comment: @JustaBreitGuy anyway, I didn't want to be an ass; as u have learned already u need actually ask a question to get the answer, and also not duplicate the same things. Hope u solved your problem.

Comment: @knowbody I didnt ask anywhere near the same question as the other user reported(it's very clear if you read). I updated my problem if you actually care. If not please leave.

Comment: I have seen that u updated ur question and I'm glad and happy. Calm down a bit, if u want to chat u are welcome to invite me to one of the chat rooms for longer talk. calm down a bit, no one is leaving anywhere lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons this might not have worked:

1. The code (assuming it works for your partner) may not recognize some of the imports. When you type in eclipse it imports the imports you need as you type, even if you re-import it it may not see that is where it is needed, if this is the issue try hovering over the code outlined in red and picking a fix.
2. He/She may be importing and or referencing something you do not have. This could be because of a version off or an add-on on of you has and the other does not, simply ask him/her to solve this issue.
3. To transfer java code (using eclipse) I personally copy the entire work space fold I assigned it rather than just the code its self, this will also insure they have all the dependent files needed (like images or sound files if it were a game).
4. If you are running different versions of Mac OS it could also effect the java code however this is unlikely, I tend to use windows or Linux when programming so I do not know all of the slight differences that there may be with Mac versions.

If you have a file sharing server, work station, or some other way to write code at the same time you could try importing your project to that so this issue wont occur again. Its good to see new programmers, keep it up and never be afraid to ask a questions everyone on this site is more than happy to help! Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Well, as you can see from the comments above, its a major turn off to ask questions when I know I am going to get attacked by people that think they control the site. Thank you for the help tho

Comment: Don't let them turn you off of this site, most are very willing to help, also I believe what Kevin Sadler said may be the cause of your issue in this particular code. Again good luck to your and your partner!

Answer (score 1):

One potential difference in your code and your partner on the MacOS must be that you are specifying the path to a file in two locations in the code:

C:\Users\Raghav\Desktop\poly.dat

If there are problems writing to the file then an Exception will occur. The same file name is used twice in the code and even if this is "test code" it would be a good idea to specify the name of the file once:

```
static final String DATA_FILE = "C:\\Users\\Raghav\\Desktop\\poly.dat";
```

and refer to DATA_FILE in the code.

The problem may not be this, unfortunately your question is quite vague about the nature of the problem, you say "nothing works" or it "works well on his Mac but not on mine". This is what Code-Guru and knowbody have been asking. If you could elaborate on the problem we might be able to give a better answer. For example: does the program not run? Does the program crash with an exception, and what is the exception? Does the program not behave as expected (what does it do, what should it be doing)?

Comment: Hey @kevin , I uploaded pictures of the problem!

Comment: Who is using the Mac and who is using PC? Is the problem that the dialog from recordPolygon() is not displayed?

Comment: Its all not displayed.  He is on a PC and I am on a Mac. I thought we were both Mac but I was wrong. recordPolygon() isnt displayed, as well as all the buttons.

Comment: OK - the other platform dependant issue is the mouse buttons. On the PC there are three mouse buttons and Button 3, the right mouse button, needs to be clicked to perform the closing of the polygon. I would guess that the Mac just has two buttons, and so as a quick test I would change the code to act on MouseEvent.BUTTON2 and see if that helps.

Comment: Also the other problem is that the Buttons Panel is not appearing and that the JPanel is not Black. I believe that, getting back to my original answer attempt ;) that the problem there is the file name, you have got a PC file name in your code, you need to change it to something on the Mac, if you just set it to a filename without a path (poly.dat) it should put the file in your project directory in Eclipse, if that is where you are running it.

Comment: ya I changed the path but it changed nothing

Comment: Are you running it from Eclipse? At the bottom of the Eclipse Window look for a tab that says "Console" if there are any errors running the program then they will appear here and would give a clue why createButtonsPanel() doesn't work.

Comment: No errors...just prints some texts every time the user clicks

Answer (score 0):

Well... not much of a question...
But if you're looking for tips on how to edit code between two people, I recommend using a terminal and vim that can be ssh'd into.